# HibernateCriteriaBuilder Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have a domain

```
Author{
   String name
   String AuthorId
   hasMany = [books:Book]
}
```

and

```
Book{
   String title
   String publisher
   belongsTo = [author:Author]
}
```

The only input I can have is AuthorId. With the use of this value how to obtain the records for domain Book using HibernetCriteriaBuilder `eq(propertyName, propertyValue)`

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before going to the answer, few check points:-
1. `id` id by default bound to domain class, you might not need an `AuthorId`.
2. Grails goes by convention. you would like to go with `authorId` instead of `AuthorId` to avoid erroneous states .

If you have gone through [this page](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) then by now you would have the basic idea about `criteria` in grails. In addition to that, `criteria` can also be used in `associations`.

In your use case, you can do something like this:-
If you want to get all the `Books` from an `Author`

```
def books = Author.createCriteria().get{
      eq('AuthorId', authorId)
}.books
```

But that is a lengthy process, this can be done very easily indeed

`def books = Author.findByAuthorId(authorId)?.books`.
Why do we need a Criteria?

Grails way is much simpler:
`def books = Author.get(id)?.books`

In criteria this becomes:

```
def books = Author.createCriteria().get{
          idEq("abc123") //'abc123' is your authorId
    }.books
```